# Reply to author message after 1 hour in Discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

How i reply to message after 1 hour in Discord.js v13

```js
client.on('message', msgg => {
  if (msgg.content === 'hi') {
    msgg.reply('hello :smile:')
  }
});
//send reply after 1h
```

Comment: `setTimeout(fn, 1000 * 60 * 60)` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **message** event in discord.js v13 is renamed to **messageCreate**.
And to delay an operation you can use the function **setTimeout()**

```js
client.on('messageCreate', msgg => {
    if (msgg.content === 'hi') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            msgg.reply('hello :smile:')
        }, 3600000) // 3600000ms = 1hr
    }
});
```